# How many subsets contain a or b and does not contain c or d

Tags: combinatorics

For example, if X was subsets of {1,2,3,4,5}. How many X (contains 1 OR contains 2) AND (does not contain 3 OR does not contain 4).

Listing out all of X:

(1),
(2),
(1, 2),
(1, 3),
(1, 4),
(1, 5),
(2, 3),
(2, 4),
(2, 5),
(1, 2, 3),
(1, 2, 4),
(1, 2, 5),
(1, 3, 5),
(1, 4, 5),
(2, 3, 5),
(2, 4, 5),
(1, 2, 3, 5),
(1, 2, 4, 5)

Gives n(X) = 18.

How can this be calculated mathematically?

Comment: Have you heard of "Inclusion-exclusion"?

Comment: Even simpler... pick a valid subset of $\{1,2\}$.  There are $3$ choices (*all but empty*).  Pick a valid subset of $\{3,4\}$ there are three choices (*all but $\{3,4\}$*).  Last, pick a valid subset of $\{5\}$, there are two choices.  This gives $3\times 3\times 2=18$

Comment: @JMoravitz Yes I have, I understand each side of the AND can be calculated using Inclusion-exclusion [2^(5-1) + 2^(5-1) - 2^(5-2)], but I am not sure how to tie both sides together.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thank you, I was able to apply that logic to larger sets and obtaining a correct answer, but do you mind explaining the logic behind it in more detail?